# Probability of an outcome that has a 25% chance to occur, occurring 3 times out of 4?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to figure this out and I keep getting overwhelmed by all the variables, lose focus and then find myself starting over again. I looking for help.

A has a 25% of occurring while B has a 75% chance of occurring.

What is the percent chance that A will occur 3 times out of 4 and what is the probability that A will occur 2 times in a row? This seems like it should be so simple to figure out. Ugh. Sorry if it sounds dumb.

Comment: Are the $3/4$ and 2 in a row separate questions, or do you want the probability of both of those happening in the same event?

Comment: 3 out of 4 is its own and 2 times in a row is also its own.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of obtaining *exactly* $k$ successes in $n$ independent trials with identical success rate $p$ is: $\newcommand{\ch}[2]{~{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}~}\ch n k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ .   This may also be written as:

$$X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,p) \quad\implies\quad \mathsf P(X=x)=\dbinom n k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

This may be familiar to you, if you've encountered the *Binomial Distribution* in your studies.

Make use of this.

> Ie: $X\sim\mathcal {Bin}(4,0.25)\implies \mathsf P(X=3)=\ldots$
>
>  Ie: $Y\sim\mathcal {Bin}(2,0.25)\implies \mathsf P(Y=2)=\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

The question does not sound dumb.

Let's start from one experiment. You are going to make an experiment, what are the chances, that outcome would be A? This question is trivial, this probability is given, it's $P_A$.

Now you are going to make two experiments. What are the chances that outcome of the first experiment would be $A$ and outcome of the second one would be $B$? It's $P_A * P_B$. Why is it so? I could refer to some rule, but I would not. This should become obvious.

Now you are going to make 4 experiments and what are the chances that outcomes would be $A, A, A, B$ (in exactly this order)? It's $P_A * P_A * P_A * P_B$.

Now you should carefully write down all the possible series of outcome which result to "3 A's and one B" and calculate the probability of each series. There should be 4 possible series, probability of each of them is the same. Now you add up probabilities of each series and the final answer would be $$4 * P_A^3 * P_B = 4 * (1/4)^3 * (3/4) = 3/64$$

Now what is the probability of two A's come in a row? I suggest the following approach. Write down all the possible series of outcomes:

A A A A

A A A B

...

There should be 16 of them. Next step: mark only those series which has two consecutive A's. Next step: calculate probability of each marked series (f.e. probability of series "B A A B" would be $P_B * P_A * P_A * P_B = P_A^2 * P_B^2$. Next and final step: add up all the calculated probabilities.